# Espresso: clicking one of many textviews with same Id

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

How to click a single textview out of different textviews, with same Id. These are the child of linear layout.They have text which was given dynamically like A, B, C, D to the textview having id txt_option_index.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/option_rl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/border">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/topMarginU2"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:id="@+id/option_sign_bg_rl">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_option_index"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_white_answer"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="A"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/optiontext"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMarginU2"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/topMarginU2"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option_sign_bg_rl"
android:text="option one found"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/topMarginU2"
android:clickable="true"
android:singleLine="false"
style="@style/txt_14_light_hex_grey_Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried:

```
ViewInteraction relativeLayout = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.txt_option_index),
withParent(withId(R.id.option_sign_bg_rl)),withText("B")));
relativeLayout.perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

and

```
ViewInteraction rr = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.txt_option_index),withText("A")));    rr.perform(click());
```

and

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.txt_option_index),hasSibling(withText("A")))).perform(click());
```

but no luck,
Error

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException
```

Comment: try to use `onData()` matcher instead of `onView`. Here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378552/in-espresso-how-to-choose-one-the-view-who-have-same-id-to-avoid-ambiguousviewm

Comment: I have tried on `onData()` but it is of no use.And I have also tried `onPosition()` but not useful as it is not a gridview with position value. In this case there is only one textview which is used multiple times to show options of a question. These option are created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag on textView in activity or fragment for Example:

```
binding.optiontext.tag = "Something you want to set unique"
```

and In test you can test like :

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.optiontext),withText("A"),withTagvalue(equalTo("your tag")))
```

I hope this helps.