# What does this error "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found more than one sub-view matching holder with view: has descendant: with id:" mean?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

I'm using espresso to test an Android application with a recyclerview, and I keep getting this exception.The issue happens when the method,

onView(withId(R.id.playing_recycler)).perform(scrollTo(hasDescendant(withId(R.id.header))));

is called.

The whole Error is here:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: has descendant: with id: com.refactor:id/header' on view 'with id: com.refactor:id/playing_recycler'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.ui.home.nowplaying.BaseNowPlayingFragmentEspressoTest.checkNowPlayingMoreLikeThisDoesExist(BaseNowPlayingFragmentEspressoTest.java:197)
at com.ui.home.playing.LikeThisTest.testThisIsDisplayed(LikeThisTest.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at com.test.base.DelayedFinishActivityTestRule$DelayedFinishActivityTestStatement.evaluate(DelayedFinishActivityTestRule.java:226)
at android.support.test.rule.ServiceTestRule$ServiceStatement.evaluate(ServiceTestRule.java:329)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1996)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found more than one sub-view matching holder with view: has descendant: with id: com.refactor:id/header

*** Matched ViewHolder item at position: 2 ***

View Hierarchy:
+>PercentRelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->TypeFaceTextView{id=2131690060, res-name=more_like_this_header, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=More like this, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|


*** Matched ViewHolder item at position: 7 ***

View Hierarchy:
+>PercentRelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->TypeFaceTextView{id=2131690060, res-name=more_like_this_header, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=true, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=More like this, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|

at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ScrollToViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:361)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Seems to be literally what error said. You have two views with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should override
getItemId(int position) 
and make sure your id is unique

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your keyboard configuration? You should set your keyboard to english and disable swipe

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue and the only way i solved it was to have a custom matcher that could select only one of the views found. your errors shows that multiple views were found with the matcher so espresso cannot make a decision. try this:

```
public static Matcher<View> withIndex(final Matcher<View> matcher, final int index) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            int currentIndex = 0;

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with index: ");
                description.appendValue(index);
                matcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                return matcher.matches(view) && currentIndex++ == index;
            }
        };
    }
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
 Matcher<View> matcher = allOf(withIndex(withId(R.id.myview),1));
        onView(matcher).perform(click());
```

special thanks to the author of the matcher. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756832/835883)