# How to get EditText View from multiple identical id's from a reused Fragment with Espresso?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-espresso

I'm trying to use `onView()` to get an EditText view that lives inside of a fragment but every EditText in each fragment has the same id.

Given this pseudo-code:

```
<Activity>
    <Fragment>
         <EditText android:id="@+id/input" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
         <EditText android:id="@+id/input" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
         <EditText android:id="@+id/input" />
    </Fragment>
</Activity>
```

In my test case, I'm doing

```
onView(withId(R.id.input)).perform(typeText("foo"));
```

On run, I'm getting `with id: com.foo.bar.foobar:id/input' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.`. The view hierarchy is below: (I moved the 'MATCHES' before the element for readability)

```
View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2} 
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2} 
|
+-->ViewStub{id=16909295, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
|
+--->FitWindowsLinearLayout{id=2131427402, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2} 
|
+---->ViewStubCompat{id=2131427403, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
|
+---->ContentFrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
|
+----->ConstraintLayout{id=2131427422, res-name=constraintLayout, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=7} 
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=2131427423, res-name=stepHeader, visibility=VISIBLE, width=321, height=140, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=380.0, y=168.0, text=Step 1:, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=2131427425, res-name=stepTitle, visibility=VISIBLE, width=521, height=88, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=280.0, y=361.0, text=Basic Information, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+------>AppCompatTextView{id=2131427426, res-name=stepInstruction, visibility=VISIBLE, width=141, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=470.0, y=712.0, text=Name, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+------>AppCompatButton{id=2131427427, res-name=nextButton, visibility=VISIBLE, width=231, height=126, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=425.0, y=1479.0, text=Next, input-type=0, ime-target=true, has-links=false} 
|
+------>AppCompatButton{id=2131427424, res-name=backButton, visibility=VISIBLE, width=231, height=126, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=21.0, y=21.0, text=Back, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>ConstraintLayout{id=2131427428, res-name=progressBarContainer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=105, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1689.0, child-count=2}
|
+------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131427429, res-name=progressBar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=105, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Progress bar, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------->View{id=2131427430, res-name=progressIndicator, visibility=VISIBLE, width=154, height=11, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=94.0}
|
+------>ConstraintLayout{id=2131427431, res-name=stepContainer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=696, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=783.0, child-count=6}
|
+------->ConstraintLayout{id=2131427436, res-name=viewStepInput, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=696, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
****MATCHES****
+-------->AppCompatEditText{id=2131427437, res-name=userInput, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1038, height=118, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x1 imeOptions=0xc000005 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=null label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null hintLocales=null contentMimeTypes=null ], x=21.0, y=289.0, text=, input-type=1, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+------->ConstraintLayout{id=2131427436, res-name=viewStepInput, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->GridView{id=2131427439, res-name=selector_grid, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+------->ConstraintLayout{id=2131427436, res-name=viewStepInput, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
****MATCHES****
+-------->AppCompatEditText{id=2131427437, res-name=userInput, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x1 imeOptions=0xc000005 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=null label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null hintLocales=null contentMimeTypes=null ], x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=1, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+------->ConstraintLayout{id=2131427436, res-name=viewStepInput, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->GridView{id=2131427439, res-name=selector_grid, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+------->ConstraintLayout{id=2131427436, res-name=viewStepInput, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+-------->GridView{id=2131427439, res-name=selector_grid, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+------->ConstraintLayout{id=2131427436, res-name=viewStepInput, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
****MATCHES****
+-------->AppCompatEditText{id=2131427437, res-name=userInput, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x1 imeOptions=0xc000005 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=null label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null hintLocales=null contentMimeTypes=null ], x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=1, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
|
+->View{id=16908336, res-name=navigationBarBackground, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=126, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1794.0}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1566)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.newfoundry.skyline.facialrecognitionkioskapp.ActivityRegistrationScreenTest.testFilledInputFieldShouldIncrementCurrentStepOnNext(ActivityRegistrationScreenTest.java:73)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
```

I've tried doing:

```
EditText input = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag("foo")
            .getView()
            .findViewById(R.id.input);

onView(withId(input));
```

But am running into issues with that as well. I haven't been able to find anything addressing this specific issue. Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the view hierarchy printed below the error message?

Comment: added the view hierarchy!

Comment: Is this relevant to solution to your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756832/1597616.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you have to differentiate the TextViews in some way.  Assume the first fragment has the id "fragment1", the second fragment has the id "fragment2", and so on.

Then you could use

```
onView(allOf(withParent(withId(R.id.fragment1)),instanceOf(EditText.class))).perform(typeText("foo"));
```

to only select the single TextView in that fragment and use it in your test case.

Comment: The problem is only when using Espresso in the test suite rather than getting them within the Activity. Regarding the issue with findFragmentByTag, the `onView` method is looking for a Matcher<View>

Comment: Did the changes help?  I don't know if you get notifications when I edit the original post.

Comment: Just saw this and going to try it once I fix something real quick

Comment: No problem!  Glad it worked. Sorry I couldn't get to correcting it sooner and thanks for the check!