# Espresso : How to get the exact TextView from an LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, automation, android-espresso

I have started using Espresso for automating my tests and the problem I face is, am not able to match the exact textview from my xml file.

Sample xml be like:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.xx.com/apk/res-auto"

android:id="@+id/filter_sort_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="2dp">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:shrinkColumns="0">

    <TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dropdown_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_triangle" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Am trying to check whether the id 'dropdown_title' is present and have to get the text from it. Code I used:

```
    onView(allOf(
    withId(R.id.dropdown_title),
    withParent(withId(R.id.filter_sort_layout)))).
    check(matches(isDisplayed();
```

But, it throws me error saying,

> 'android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: xx.debug:id/dropdown_title and has parent matching: with id: xx/filter_sort_layout)

View Hierarchy:

```
    +>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
    |
    +->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1776, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
    |
    +-->ViewStub{id=16909227, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
    |
    +-->FrameLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=72.0, child-count=1}
    |
    +--->FitWindowsLinearLayout{id=2131820663, res-name=action_bar_root, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
    |'
```

I have tried using `descendantOfA()` and also `hasSibling()` methods. Doesn't work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

I think your current code is failing because `dropdown_title` is not an immediate child of `filter_sort_layout`.  Rather, `dropdown_title` is a descendant of `filter_sort_layout`.  Use `isDescendantOfA` instead:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.dropdown_title),
       isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.filter_sort_layout))))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

**Edit:**

From comments below it appears that the OP actually has multiples views in the app all with the same name.  The duplicate link covers how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried isDescendantOfA(), but still am facing the same issue.

Comment: So you get the same error with `isDescendantOfA` ?

Comment: Yes, I used exactly the same code and it throws me this error : android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: xx:id/dropdown_title and is descendant of a: with id: xx:id/filter_sort_layout)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.

Comment: Hmmm...do you have more than one `filter_sort_layout` layout tag in your app?  This seems to be what the error message is saying.

Comment: The view is defined only once in xx.xml file but is used multiple times in all filterviews of the app. In that case, how do we match it?

Comment: @Pinky You're going to need to [write some custom code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378552/in-espresso-how-to-choose-one-the-view-who-have-same-id-to-avoid-ambiguousviewm) most likely.  If I were you, I would just use unique view names everywhere.  There are many arguments for using unique names always just as a matter of good Android practice alone.

Comment: Cool.. Thanks :)