# espresso select first match of row in RecyclerView which descendant matching to specific text

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I would like to click on the first matching row in recyclerView which item has descendant matching to specific text.

For now, I have

```
 onView(withId(R.id.news)).perform(
                actionOnItem(hasDescendant(withText("text")),click())
        )
```

which throws ambiguousViewMatcherException. I tried to add first matcher from 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967627/1177865)

```
onView(withId(R.id.news)).perform(
                    actionOnItem(hasDescendant(first(withText("text"))),click())
            )
```

but it time out.

```
public static Matcher<View> first(Matcher<View> expected ){

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        private boolean first = false;

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View item) {

            if( expected.matches(item) && !first ){
                return first = true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Matcher.first( " + expected.toString() + " )" );
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52737309/6654475) question may help you.

Comment: You need to make custom macher for RecyclerView check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52828004/10111447) out.

Comment: thanks for the comment but this question has been quite a bit old and I didn't continue this work anymore

Comment: @AnassNAZIH What if I don't know the position I want to click? Just like in the original question, I want to select the first RecyclerView item that contains some text when there are multiple items with that same text.