# Espresso - Check RecyclerView items are ordered correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

How to go about checking whether RecyclerView items are displayed in the correct order using Espresso? I'm trying to test it checking it by the text for the title of each element.

When I try this piece of code it works to click the element but can't go on to instead of performing a click trying to Assert the text for the element

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv_metrics)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

When I try to use a custom matcher instead I keep getting the error

```
Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: mypackage_name:id/rv_metrics'
```

I know now `onData doesn't work for RecyclerView` but before that I was trying to use a custom matcher for this task.

```
 public static Matcher<Object> hasTitle(final String inputString) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, Metric>(Metric.class) {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(Metric metric) {

            return inputString.equals(metric.getMetric());

        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(org.hamcrest.Description description) {
            description.appendText("with title: ");
        }
    };
}
```

I also tried something like this but it obviously doesn't work due to the type given as parameter to the actionOnItemAtPosition method but would we have something similar to it that could maybe work?

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv_metrics)).check(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, ViewAssertions.matches(withText("Weight"))));
```

What am I missing here please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `RecyclerView` does not support `onData`

Comment: Owh, really?! Didn't know that but have confirmed it through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zi7v47kYKrk. I guess I'll need to try to make that work instead `onView(withId(R.id.rv_metrics)).perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));` but for getting the text instead. Do you have any suggestion on how to do that please as that was what I was trying yesterday but couldn't make it work? Thanks very much again for your help @Mosius. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think here is what you need in this git repo:
https://github.com/dannyroa/espresso-samples/blob/master/RecyclerView/app/src/androidTest/java/com/dannyroa/espresso_samples/recyclerview/RecyclerViewMatcher.java

Comment: Thank you @Mosius. I've updated the question using the feedback you provided me about the onData method. I'm just not sure if I can fully understand the sample you last sent me. This is only my third day using Espresso (two of them trying to solve this issue) so this sample still looks a bit difficult for me to grasp I'm afraid. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: I was trying something like this but it doesn't seem to work `onView(withId(R.id.rv_metrics)).check(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, ViewAssertions.matches(withText("Weight"))));`

Comment: Thank you very much @mosius for your detailed answer. I'll spend the day today trying to make it work and will make sure I'll get back and accept your answer when able to use it on my code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it's been mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists#recycler-view-list-items), `RecyclerView` objects work differently than `AdapterView` objects, so `onData()` cannot be used to interact with them.

In order to find a view at specific position of a `RecyclerView` you need to implement a custom [`RecyclerViewMatcher`](https://github.com/dannyroa/espresso-samples/blob/master/RecyclerView/app/src/androidTest/java/com/dannyroa/espresso_samples/recyclerview/RecyclerViewMatcher.java) like below:

```
public class RecyclerViewMatcher {
    private final int recyclerViewId;

    public RecyclerViewMatcher(int recyclerViewId) {
        this.recyclerViewId = recyclerViewId;
    }

    public Matcher<View> atPosition(final int position) {
        return atPositionOnView(position, -1);
    }

    public Matcher<View> atPositionOnView(final int position, final int targetViewId) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            Resources resources = null;
            View childView;

            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                String idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId);
                if (this.resources != null) {
                    try {
                        idDescription = this.resources.getResourceName(recyclerViewId);
                    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException var4) {
                        idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)",
                                                      new Object[] { Integer.valueOf
                                                          (recyclerViewId) });
                    }
                }

                description.appendText("with id: " + idDescription);
            }

            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

                this.resources = view.getResources();

                if (childView == null) {
                    RecyclerView recyclerView =
                        (RecyclerView) view.getRootView().findViewById(recyclerViewId);
                    if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.getId() == recyclerViewId) {
                        childView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if (targetViewId == -1) {
                    return view == childView;
                } else {
                    View targetView = childView.findViewById(targetViewId);
                    return view == targetView;
                }

            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then use it in your test case in this way:

```
@Test
void testCase() {
    onView(new RecyclerViewMatcher(R.id.rv_metrics)
        .atPositionOnView(0, R.id.txt_title))
        .check(matches(withText("Weight")))
        .perform(click());

    onView(new RecyclerViewMatcher(R.id.rv_metrics)
        .atPositionOnView(1, R.id.txt_title))
        .check(matches(withText("Height")))
        .perform(click());
}
```

Comment: Hi @mosius, I've changed your answer just to call it creating a new object for the class adding the word new to it. I'm getting another error now (`AppCompatTextView{id=2131297101, res-name=tv_title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=348, height=54, has-focus=false, has-links=false}"`) but think it may be for something else, probably because the text is html, so am accepting your answer here. Thanks really very much again for your help. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos make sure that your **view is visible on the screen**,some times scrolling to that position or closing soft keyboard will solve the problem

Comment: Ideally, you should make `matchesSafely()` throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)` returns `null` for an invalid `position`. Otherwise a generic error `NullPointerException` appears, which is very confusing.

Comment: What if our recycler view contains custom views? My recycler view contains a list of custom XML views with a primary and secondary text

Answer (score 4):

If somebody is interested in the Kotlin version, here it is

```
fun hasItemAtPosition(position: Int, matcher: Matcher<View>) : Matcher<View> {
    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView::class.java) {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("has item at position $position : ")
            matcher.describeTo(description)
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(item: RecyclerView?): Boolean {
            val viewHolder = item?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
            return matcher.matches(viewHolder?.itemView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also describe how to use it. We are unable to use it the same way we are able to use Mosius's answer

Answer (score 1):

I simplified a bit Mosius answer:

```
public static Matcher<View> hasItemAtPosition(final Matcher<View> matcher, final int position) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has item at position " + position + ": ");
            matcher.describeTo(description);
        }
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
            return matcher.matches(viewHolder.itemView);
        }
    };
}
```

We pass `Matcher` to the function so we can provide further conditions. Example usage:

```
onView(hasItemAtPosition(hasDescendant(withText("Item 1")), 0)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(hasItemAtPosition(hasDescendant(withText("Item 2")), 1)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The original problem has been solved but am posting an answer here as found the **Barista** library solves this problem in one **single line of code**.

```
assertDisplayedAtPosition(R.id.rv_metrics, 0, R.id.tv_title, "weight");
```

It's made on top of Espresso and the documentation for it can be found [here](https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista)

Hope this may be helpful to someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a matcher on a position in `RecyclerView`, then you can try to create a custom `Matcher<View>`:

```
public static Matcher<View> hasItemAtPosition(int position, Matcher<View> matcher) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {

        @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has item: ");
            matcher.describeTo(description);
            description.appendText(" at position: " + position);
        }

        @Override protected boolean matchesSafely(RecyclerView view) {
            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
            int type = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, type);
            adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
            return matcher.matches(holder.itemView);
        }
    };
}
```

And you can use it for example:

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv_metrics)).check(matches(0, hasDescendant(withText("Weight")))))
```